# Is the order of elements on a C# List<T> deterministic?

Tags: c#

I've always thought otherwise, but recently I had the need to know:

If I add elements to a list in a certain order, am I guaranteed to find then always on the same order?

Thanks!

Comment: What would be the point if they didn't provide such a guarantee. They are indexable; an indexable collection that didn't maintain such a guarantee would be useless.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes; you control the ordering of a `List<T>`.

You can assume that any .NET collection with a `list[int]` indexer has a predictable ordering; otherwise, the numerical index wouldn't make any sense. By comparison, it's not possible to use a numerical index with a `Dictionary<K,V>`, and when you enumerate a dictionary, the ordering isn't guaranteed.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is deterministic. Bear in mind that if you want to use `List<T>` across threads then, as with anything, you can't guarantee the order in which the interactions would happen.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. List is an indexed collection; using Add() to put elements into the List will cause them to be indexed in the order they're added.